# Need to modify a JQuery to not fire off of button clicks within a <TR> area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a JQuery that expands and hides a `TR` and this `TR` serves as a "description area" that can expand/close when the `TR` above it (the Movie item) is clicked.

Here is an image to depict this, blue is the description area that each item expands when the `TR` above it (the Movie item) is clicked
[image]

The problem is that this description area expands whenever ANYTHING in the TR is clicked, I do not want this to occur for button clicks (and I cannot just add a .stopPropogation on buttons as they have their own scripts).

Could someone help me modify my row expansion script so that buttons do not activate this JQuery?

Thank you!

Here is my button and content (two `TR`'s)

```
<tr>
     <td class="col-lg-3">
         <span class="item-display">
             <span style="font-size: 17px">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.showtime)
             </span>
         </span>
         <span class="item-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.showtime)
             </span>
      </td>

      <td class="col-lg-3">
          <span class="item-display">
                <span style="font-size: 17px">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location.Location1)
                </span>
           </span>
           <span class="item-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Location.Location1)
                </span>
      </td>

      <td class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-3">
            <span style="visibility:hidden" class="ID col-lg-1">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)</span>

            <span class="item-edit-button">
                  <button type="button" onclick="editFunction(this)" class=" btn btn-warning col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-0"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Edit</button>
            </span>

            <span class="item-save-button">
                 <button type="button" onclick="saveFunction(this)" class="btn btn-success col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-4"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Save</button>
            </span>

            <!-- Modal Button-->
            <span class="item-delete-button">
                  <button class="btn btn-danger col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@item.ID" onclick="deleteStart(this)">
             <span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Delete
                   </button>
             </span>

             <!-- Modal -->
                 <div class="modal fade" id="@item.ID" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                       <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <span style="font-size: 20px">Are you sure you want to delete Employee: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location.Location1)?</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" onclick="deleteStopped(this)" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                    <button type="button" onclick="deleteFunction(this)" class="btn btn-danger">Confirm Delete</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td colspan="12">
                    <p style="font-size: 17px; font-style: italic; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif">
                        Show ID: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
                        <br />
                        Location ID: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location.ID)
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Here is the JQuery

```
<script>

    $(function () {
        $("td[colspan=12]").find("p").hide();
        $("td[colspan=12]").addClass("nopadding");

        $("tr").click(function () {
            var $target = $(this);
            var $detailsTd = $target.find("td[colspan=12]");
            if ($detailsTd.length) {
                $detailsTd.find("p").slideUp();
                $detailsTd.addClass("nopadding");
            } else {
                $detailsTd = $target.next().find("td[colspan=12]");
                $detailsTd.find("p").slideToggle();
                $detailsTd.toggleClass("nopadding");
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I don't know jQuery but maybe change the "tr" to "button"?

Comment: Filter event target inside relevant handler. Now not sure why you can't stop propagation, a jsfiddle would make your issue clearer to spot

Comment: Hello! I am still very new to all of this stuff, so I would make a JSFiddle but I am not quite at that point yet with everything occurring in my code. And I cannot do a stopPropagation as then my Modal events are halted on button clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the click handler you can simply check if the original target element was not a button:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j7LNE/

```
$(function () {
    $("td[colspan=12]").find("p").hide();
    $("td[colspan=12]").addClass("nopadding");

    $("tr").click(function (e) {
        if (!$(e.target).is('button')){
            var $target = $(this);
            var $detailsTd = $target.find("td[colspan=12]");
            if ($detailsTd.length) {
                $detailsTd.find("p").slideUp();
                $detailsTd.addClass("nopadding");
            } else {
                $detailsTd = $target.next().find("td[colspan=12]");
                $detailsTd.find("p").slideToggle();
                $detailsTd.toggleClass("nopadding");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

*Apologies for using your source as the output HTML :)*

Comment: This is now my 1000th SO answer! Applause anyone? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a check between `event.target` and `this`.

`event.target` is always the object which fired the event first, so you can check if it was your TR or the button.

Check this: http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Comment: I shall be sure to look into this for future reference. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@TrueBlueAussie in comments gave you the correct answer. Either, if you want to 'turn off' expanding by any DOM element which contains `onclick` attribute you can set something like:

```
$("tr :not([onclick])").click(function () {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Does not work: This will not select the TR itself, so nothing happens unless you click on a child element: http://jsfiddle.net/j7LNE/1/ (which is why I deleted my comment) :)

Comment: This concept makes sense, however it halted all TR expansion :/

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Right, it will not work. So the best I think it would be to use e.target which someone pointed above:)